# Swift || How to filter kid array by parent array elements?

Tags: swift

i have two data models as below:

```swift
class Card {
    let type: String
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    
    init(
        type: String,
        name: String,
        icon: String
    ) {
        self.type = type
        self.icon = icon
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Product {
    let type: String? // please watch out here is optional value
    let imageUrl: String
    let content: String
    
    init(
        type: String?,
        imageUrl: String,
        content: String
    ) {
        self.type = type
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.content = content
    }
}
```

And I managed to get the above two entities mapped data with API response, right now I got a new requirement that needs to merge the above two data entities as the following structure. and products be filtered by same `type` which included in both `Card` and `Product`

```swift
class MergedData {
    let type: String // same "type" with "Product.type"
    let name: String
    let icon: String
    let products: [Product] // products inserted here should have same "type" 
   
    init(
        type: String,
        name: String,
        icon: String,
        products: [Product]
    ) {
        self.type = type
        self.icon = icon
        self.name = name
        self.products = products
    }
    
}
```

lets say we have a `DemoViewModel` here

```swift
class DemoViewModel {
    
    var cards: [Card]
    var products: [Product]
    var mergedData: [MergedData] = [] 
    
    init(cards: [Card],
         products: [Product]) {
        self.cards = cards  
        self.products = products
    }
    
    func getMergedData() -> [MergedData] {
        // how to write here ?
    }
}
```

how to write the content of `getMergedData` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
func getMergedData() -> [MergedData] {
    cards.map{ card in
        MergedData(type: card.type, name: card.name, icon: card.icon, products: products.filter{product in product.type == card.type })
    }
}
```

this itterates through all cards creates a new `MergedData` for each card and assigns all `Product` that have the same type.

Comment: thanks very much!!! thats really works well for me.

Comment: @zitherC if this answer solves your problem then you should accept it. That is a strong norm on this site. Up-voting is optional, but generates goodwill.

Answer (score 1):

I would first group the products array on `type` and use that  for looking up the products for a card

This first solution will only merge data for cards that has matching products

```
func merge(cards: [Card], with products: [Product]) -> [MergedData] {
    let groupedProducts = Dictionary(grouping: products, by: \Product.type)

    return cards.compactMap { card in
        guard let products = groupedProducts[card.type] else { return nil }
        return MergedData(card: card, products: products)
    }
}
```

but if you want to create a MergedData instance for each Card instance you can replace the last part with

```
return cards.map { card in
    let products = groupedProducts[card.type]
    return MergedData(card: card, products: products)
}
```

Note that I created a custom init for this to make the code cleaner

```
init(card: Card, products: [Product]?) {
    type = card.type
    icon = card.icon
    name = card.name
    self.products = products ?? []
}
```

Comment: thanks very much!!! thats really works well for me.